# onConsoleMessage() only returns first Console

Tags: android-webview

Here's my code

```
webV.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            @Override
            public void onConsoleMessage(String message, int line, String ID){
                textView.append("\n"+message+" at line "+Integer.toString(line));
            }

        });
```

So, it returns console message to the `TextView` but unfortunately I only get the first console log. Where I've did two error in js myself to test. How can I get the rests.

**Notice**
I've searched in Google & SO but didn't found methods that can help me or my search query wasn't clear enough.